# Import/Post CSV files into ServiceNow

Tags: post, import, servicenow

We have a requirement for a CSV file to be pushed to the instance, imported and an incident created. I have created the import table and transformation map, and I've successfully tested them manually.

However, when I've attempted to use the instructions from ServiceNow documents site Post CSV files to Import Set nothing happens. The screen goes blank after I get prompted for login credentials.

When I check the system logs and import logs all I see is the error "java.lang.NullPointerException".

My url is basically the following one: https://.service-now.com/sys_import.do?sysparm_import_set_tablename=&sysparm_transform_after_load=true&uploadfile=

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: In order for this to work (according to the docs|https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/jakarta-platform-administration/page/administer/import-sets/task/t_PostCSVOrExcelFilesToImportSet.html) you should do some POST HTTP call carrying the file & the basic authentication parameters? it looks like you are trying the URL in your browser manually? can you describe the scenario you are applying please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do the same thing but have it come in via an email to the my SN instance and process it using an inbound action.

```
    var type = {};
type.schedule = 'u_imp_tmpl_u_term_phr_empl_mvs_ids'; //Display name for scheduled import  -- eb9f2dae6f46a60051281ecbbb3ee4a5
type.table = 'u_imp_tmpl_u_term_phr_empl_mvs_ids'; //Import table name

gs.log('0. Process File Start');

if(type.schedule != '' && type.table != '') {
    gs.log('1. Setting up data source');
    current.name = type.schedule + ' ' + gs.nowDateTime(); //append date time to name of data source for audit
    current.import_set_table_name = type.table;
    current.import_set_table_label = "";
    current.type= "File";
    current.format = "CSV";  //"Excel CSV (tab)";
    current.header_row = 1;
    current.file_retrieval_method = "Attachment";

    var myNewDataSource = current.insert();

    gs.log('2. Data source inserted with sys_id - ' + myNewDataSource);

    //point the scheduled import record to the new data source
    var gr = new GlideRecord ('scheduled_import_set');

    gr.addQuery('name', type.schedule);
    gr.query();

    if (gr.next()) {
        gs.log('3. Found Scheduled Import definition');
        gr.data_source = myNewDataSource;
        gr.update();
        gs.log('4. Scheduled Import definition updated to point to data source just added');

        //Packages.com.snc.automation.TriggerSynchronizer.executeNow(gr);
        //Execute a scheduled script job
        SncTriggerSynchronizer.executeNow(gr);
    } else {
        // add error conditions to email somebody that this has occurred
        gs.log('5. ERROR - Unable to locate scheduled import definition. Please contact your system administrator');
    }

    gs.log('6. Inbound email processing complete');
    //gs.eventQueue("ep_server_processed",current);
    event.state="stop_processing";
} else {
    gs.log('7. Inbound email processing skipped');
}
```